# having trouble to resize images in bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://instagram.fphl1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/14268970_1251518108241488_429863245_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM0MTc4MTc5MzM1NTEwODY1NQ%3D%3D.2.l" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://instagram.fphl1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/14474249_890696994394344_5843789814981197824_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM0NTY1MzIyMjgxMTAyOTk5MA%3D%3D.2.l" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <video autoplay loop muted>
                 <source src="https://instagram.fphl1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t50.2886-16/14427920_909305109199530_1666974084291887104_n.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
            </a>
          </div>
</div>

<style>
      .thumbnail {
        margin-bottom: 7px;
      }
      video {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
       img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
</style>
```

You can also try this in JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dbj1w1by/2/).

I am able to adjust the video to fit to the size of the container, but not the img (notice the white space in the img containers). How can I fit the img to the container? Full code for template [here](http://www.bootply.com/d08bOti6Zs), in case it helps.

Comment: your images are already inside the container? can you please explain a little bit. what do you mean by fit the image ?

Comment: So sorry if I was unclear. I would like to make the size of the image the same as the container's, almost as if I were stretching the image to entirely fit the container if that makes sense. Notice how there is white space in the image containers, but no white space in the video container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Code is correct. In your image having the space for left and right. check your image.
```

Comment: You are so right! I did not notice. Getting rid of that white space programmatically is going to be more difficult than i thought

Comment: It's okay. no problem.